# Increment a number in the middle of a string

Tags: jquery, regex, attr

I have a series of strings `add[0][types]`, `add[0][name]` etc (to make an array with PHP form $_POST).

I need to pull out the `[0]` and make it `[1]`.

I have built a regex function based on some other replies, but it isn't changing the attribute, I'm not sure if my function syntax is correct:

```
newrow.find('input, select').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('name', function(i, val){return val.replace(
    /\\d+/, function(n){ return ++n; });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I think your regex is slightly off. And you can shorten your code by removing the `.each` in favor of the overload of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) that takes a function (which you are already using, slightly differently):

```
newrow.find('input, select').attr('name', function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\d+/, function(n) {
        return ++n;
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hDELW/1/

Comment: +1, however the OP also uses the function as the second argument of `attr`, and the problem was mostly in incorrect regular expression.

Comment: @VisioN: Right (I'll clarify), but he/she isn't leveraging the fact that it can be used in place of `.each`